`pdflatex` in TeX Live 2024 stops compiling SIAM article template after `tlmgr update --self && tlmgr update --all` on 8 Nov. 2024
pdflatex in TeX Live 2024 on Ubuntu 24.04 stops compiling the SIAM article template after
$ tlmgr update --self && tlmgr update --all

on 8 Nov. 2024. It worked before the update, and TeX Live 2023 is still working. Any suggestions or comments (even a confirmation that the same happens on your side) will be highly appreciated.
After the update above, pdflatex ex_article.tex failed with the following error.
! Use of \cref@override@label@type doesn't match its definition.
\refstepcounter@optarg ...cref@currentlabel \@nil 
                                                  {\@tempa }}
l.86 \begin{theorem}
                    [$LDL^T$ Factorization \cite{GoVa13}]\label{thm:bigthm}

The version of pdflatex is
$ pdflatex --version

pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024)
kpathsea version 6.4.0
Copyright 2024 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.43; using libpng 1.6.43
Compiled with zlib 1.3.1; using zlib 1.3.1
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04

The detailed log is as follows.
$ pdflatex ex_article.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.11.12)  12 NOV 2024 13:53
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**ex_article.tex
(./ex_article.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
(./siamart220329.cls
Document Class: siamart220329 2022/03/29 v1.4.4 LaTeX document e-class
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2024/11/05 v2.17t AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen141
)) (/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.st
y
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen142
) (/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count196
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 233.
\uproot@=\count197
\leftroot@=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 398.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 409.
\classnum@=\count199
\DOTSCASE@=\count266
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 495.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 498.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 619.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box52
\strutbox@=\box53
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 721.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 724.
\big@size=\dimen143
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 742.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 743.
\macc@depth=\count267
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 904.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 909.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 939.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 969.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 970.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count268
\dotsspace@=\muskip17
\c@parentequation=\count269
\dspbrk@lvl=\count270
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count271
\column@=\count272
\maxfields@=\count273
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen144
\alignsep@=\dimen145
\tagshift@=\dimen146
\tagwidth@=\dimen147
\totwidth@=\dimen148
\lineht@=\dimen149
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ntheorem/ntheorem.st
y
Style `ntheorem', Version 1.33 <2011/08/15>
Package: ntheorem 2011/08/15 1.33
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2024/03/16 v1.1e Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\theorem@style=\toks22
\theorem@@style=\toks23
\theorembodyfont=\toks24
\theoremnumbering=\toks25
\theorempreskipamount=\skip52
\theorempostskipamount=\skip53
\theoremframepreskipamount=\skip54
\theoremframepostskipamount=\skip55
\theoreminframepreskipamount=\skip56
\theoreminframepostskipamount=\skip57
\theorem@preskip=\toks26
\theorem@postskip=\toks27
\theorem@framepreskip=\toks28
\theorem@framepostskip=\toks29
\theorem@inframepreskip=\toks30
\theorem@inframepostskip=\toks31
\theoremindent=\dimen150
\theorem@indent=\dimen151
\theoremrightindent=\dimen152
\theorem@rightindent=\dimen153
\theoremheaderfont=\toks32
\theoremseparator=\toks33
\theoremprework=\toks34
\theorempostwork=\toks35
\theoremsymbol=\toks36
\qedsymbol=\toks37
\theoremkeyword=\toks38
\qedsymbol=\toks39
\thm@topsep=\skip58
\thm@topsepadd=\skip59
Package ntheorem Info: Option `thmmarks' loaded on input line 1175.
\c@endNonectr=\count274
\c@currNonectr=\count275
\mysavskip=\skip60
Package ntheorem Info: option `amsmath' handling for `thmmarks' loaded on input
 line 1175.
\thm@amstmpdepth=\dimen154
\tagwidth=\dimen155
)
\fromfoliotocopyright=\skip61
\c@section=\count276
\c@subsection=\count277
\c@subsubsection=\count278
\c@paragraph=\count279
\c@subparagraph=\count280
\c@rmnum=\count281
\c@muni=\count282
\@sectionspace=\skip62
\@negsectionspace=\skip63
\c@figure=\count283
\c@table=\count284
\abovecaptionskip=\skip64
\belowcaptionskip=\skip65
\bibindent=\dimen156

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/xr-hyper.st
y
Package: xr-hyper 2024-11-05 v7.01l eXternal References (DPC)
) (/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.st
y
Package: hyperref 2024-11-05 v7.01l Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks40
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.
sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdef
inekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescap
e.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.st
y
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexc
mds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarer
r.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
))
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2023-11-26 v2.56 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.st
y
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/get
titlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.
sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))

Package nameref Warning: The definition of \label has changed!
(nameref)                Check your packages!
(nameref)                Replacing it with the kernel definition on input line
149.

\c@section@level=\count285
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.st
y
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count286
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringen
c.sty
Package: stringenc 2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO
)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen157
\Hy@linkcounter=\count287
\Hy@pagecounter=\count288

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2024-11-05 v7.01l Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.st
y
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count289

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2024-11-05 v7.01l Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4157.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4162.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4165.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4172.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4177.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4424.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count290

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip18
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4763.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen158

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintc
alc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count291
\Field@Width=\dimen159
\Fld@charsize=\dimen160
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6042.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6047.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6050.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6057.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6062.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6067.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6072.

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.st
y
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count292
\c@Item=\count293
\c@Hfootnote=\count294
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2024-11-05 v7.01l Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.s
ty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend pac
kage
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count295
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count296

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerun
filecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniq
uecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
85.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip66
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `false' on input line 1294.
Package hyperref Info: Option `frenchlinks' set `false' on input line 1294.
Package hyperref Info: Option `naturalnames' set `false' on input line 1294.
Package hyperref Info: Option `hypertexnames' set `false' on input line 1294.
Package hyperref Info: Option `breaklinks' set `true' on input line 1294.

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.st
y
Package: graphics 2024/08/06 v1.4g Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2023/12/02 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphic
s.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 106.

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.
def
File: pdftex.def 2024/04/13 v1.2c Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.st
y
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen161
\Gin@req@width=\dimen162
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopd
f.sty
Package: epstopdf 2020-01-24 v2.11 Conversion with epstopdf on the fly (HO)

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/grfext/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2019/12/03 v1.3 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopd
f-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 504.

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf
-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
)))
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2024/09/29 v3.02 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.c
fg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 274.

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.l
tx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1349.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1365.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hypcap/hypcap.sty
Package: hypcap 2024-07-26 v1.13 Adjusting the anchors of captions (HO)

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxma
cro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
))
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm
.sty
Package: algorithm 2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating enviro
nment
 (/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count297
\float@exts=\toks41
\float@box=\box54
\@float@everytoks=\toks42
\@floatcapt=\box55
)
\@float@every@algorithm=\toks43
\c@algorithm=\count298
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.st
y
Package: cleveref 2018/03/27 v0.21.4 Intelligent cross-referencing
Package cleveref Info: `hyperref' support loaded on input line 2370.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cref on input line 2370.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Cref on input line 2370.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \crefrange on input line 2370.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Crefrange on input line 2370.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cpageref on input line 2370.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Cpageref on input line 2370.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cpagerefrange on input line 2370.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Cpagerefrange on input line 2370.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \labelcref on input line 2370.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \labelcpageref on input line 2370.
Package cleveref Info: `ntheorem' support loaded on input line 3055.
Package cleveref Info: always capitalise cross-reference names on input line 78
30.
Package cleveref Info: include cross-reference names in hyperlinks on input lin
e 7836.
Package cleveref Info: always capitalise cross-reference names on input line 78
52.
Package cleveref Info: include cross-reference names in hyperlinks on input lin
e 7852.
)
\c@currproofctr=\count299
\c@endproofctr=\count300
\c@proof=\count301
\c@currtheoremctr=\count302
\c@endtheoremctr=\count303
\c@theorem=\count304
\c@currlemmactr=\count305
\c@endlemmactr=\count306
\c@currcorollaryctr=\count307
\c@endcorollaryctr=\count308
\c@currpropositionctr=\count309
\c@endpropositionctr=\count310
\c@currdefinitionctr=\count311
\c@enddefinitionctr=\count312
 (/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty
Package: lineno 2023/05/20 line numbers on paragraphs v5.3
\linenopenalty=\count313
\output=\toks44
\linenoprevgraf=\count314
\linenumbersep=\dimen163
\linenumberwidth=\dimen164
\c@linenumber=\count315
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count316
\c@LN@truepage=\count317
\c@internallinenumber=\count318
\c@internallinenumbers=\count319
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen165
\bframerule=\dimen166
\bframesep=\dimen167
\bframebox=\box56
\linenoamsmath@ams@eqpen=\count320
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3180.
)) (./ex_shared.tex
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/
l3keys2e.sty
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-11-02 L3 programming layer (loader)

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-
pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count321
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box57
))
Package: l3keys2e 2024-08-16 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package: lipsum 2021-09-20 v2.7 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\g__lipsum_par_int=\count322
\l__lipsum_a_int=\count323
\l__lipsum_b_int=\count324

(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.te
x))
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.st
y
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm
ic.sty
Package: algorithmic 2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithmic'
\c@ALC@unique=\count325
\c@ALC@line=\count326
\c@ALC@rem=\count327
\c@ALC@depth=\count328
\ALC@tlm=\skip67
\algorithmicindent=\skip68
)
\c@currremarkctr=\count329
\c@endremarkctr=\count330
\c@currhypothesisctr=\count331
\c@endhypothesisctr=\count332
\c@currclaimctr=\count333
\c@endclaimctr=\count334
)

Package xr Warning:
No file ex_supplement.aux
LABELS NOT IMPORTED.
 on input line 23.

(./ex_article.aux)
\openout1 = `ex_article.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 37.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 37.
 (./ex_article.out) (./ex_article.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `ex_article.out'.


(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf
.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count335
\scratchdimen=\dimen168
\scratchbox=\box58
\nofMPsegments=\count336
\nofMParguments=\count337
\everyMPshowfont=\toks45
\MPscratchCnt=\count338
\MPscratchDim=\dimen169
\MPnumerator=\count339
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count340
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks46
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 40.

 (/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 40.


(/home/nuno/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)

LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:main' on page 1 undefined on input line 71.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:alg' on page 1 undefined on input line 71.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:experiments' on page 1 undefined on input line 72
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:conclusions' on page 1 undefined on input line 73
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `thm:bigthm' on page 1 undefined on input line 83.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:proof' on page 1 undefined on input line 84.

! Use of \cref@override@label@type doesn't match its definition.
\refstepcounter@optarg ...cref@currentlabel \@nil
                                                  {\@tempa }}
l.86 \begin{theorem}
                    [$LDL^T$ Factorization \cite{GoVa13}]\label{thm:bigthm}
? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14777 strings out of 473420
 238541 string characters out of 5716465
 711740 words of memory out of 5000000
 36141 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 563999 words of font info for 60 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 2685 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 89i,4n,96p,667b,459s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 7 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 1 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)


Update: a "minimal example"
The following code will trigger the same error.
\documentclass{siamart220329}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} nothing. \end{theorem}
\end{document}

So it is caused by the definition of theorem in the SIAM article template (in siamart220329.cls). Sorry that my knowledge of (La)TeX does not suffice to boil the .cls to a minimal example. The theorem environment is not defined in a simple way (in my eyes) --- I cannot even identify which part of the .cls file defines it.

Welcome to tex.sx.

What happens if you comment out (or delete) all \cref-type instructions? I.e., does the document still fail to compile?

Hi @Mico. It still fails in exactly the same way. Thanks.

Show a small but complete example that can be used for a test.

Looks like hyperref issue #360, but AFAIK this should already be fixed in hyperref 7.01l 2024-11-05 …

Hi @UlrikeFischer. Thank you for your reminder. See my updates. The error is caused by the definition of theorem in the SIAM article template (in siamart220329.cls). Sorry that my knowledge of (La)TeX does not suffice to boil the .cls to a minimal example. The theorem environment is not defined in a simple way (in my eyes) --- I cannot even identify which part of the .cls file defines it.

@cabohah no, this time it is the class.

The class redefines the kernel commands \refstepcounter and \label and so destroys new additions to these commands in the kernel, the hyperref support and the fixes for cleveref.
\let\ORIlabel\label
\let\ORIrefstepcounter\refstepcounter
\AddToHook{package/hyperref/before}{
   \let\label\ORIlabel 
   \let\refstepcounter\ORIrefstepcounter}
\documentclass{siamart220329}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} nothing. \end{theorem}
\end{document}


+1. To help casual readers, you may want to state explicitly that the 5 lines of patch instructions have to be inserted before the \documentclass instruction.

Great! Thank you! This has been reported to SIAM.

There is no response from SIAM. Maybe they are not monitoring tex@siam.org, the email address that is supposed to receive suggestions about the siamart class. Does anyone know a better way of informing SIAM?

@Nuno if you write a question in a comment more or less only me will see that. And no, I do not know how to contact them. You are using the class and the only reason I can imagine for this is that the journal required that from you, so you must know how to contact them.
